# Перестала отображается нагрузка CPU

Tags: linux, debian, cpu

Захожу в `htop`, вижу это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `atop` это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод `lscpu`:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 44
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2400.084
BogoMIPS:              4800.16
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              12288K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
```

Скрипт благодаря которому я вычислял загрузку CPU теперь выдает всегда 0%

```
read cpu a b c previdle rest < /proc/stat
prevtotal=$((a+b+c+previdle))
sleep 0.5
read cpu a b c idle rest < /proc/stat
total=$((a+b+c+idle))
CPU=$((100*( (total-prevtotal) - (idle-previdle) ) / (total-prevtotal) ))
echo $CPU
```

Вроде никаких изменений в сервере не производил.

Comment: Интереснее steal 100% в выводе atop. У вас KVM-виртуалка? KVM как раз предоставляет в гостевую систему такую информацию. Steal означает количество времени CPU, которое гипервизор не дал виртуалке, а занимался в это время какими-то своими вещами (или отдал другим виртуалкам). Производительность CPU просела? По идее steal > 0 говорит о том, что хостер продал больше виртуалок, чем может разместить на железке.

Comment: @Мелкий провадер сказал, что гипервизор не отвечает за эту функцию.

Comment: За какую "функцию"?

Comment: @Мелкий в общем переносили меня вчера на другую ноду, т.к жесткий диск начал дико тупить. Сами что-то наделали, пускай разбираются.